# How to convert misspelt strings to the correct verison in R

Tags: r, string

I have a lot of dataframes where there are a lot of inconsistencies with people's names. I want to be convert all misspelt names to the correct name, some names have 2 or 3 ways that they are commonly mispelt.

Currently I am attempting this via the code below but the output is far from what I want due to the all changes being applied to all strings.

Help fixing my code or suggesting a much better method would be much appreciated.

```
Data <- data.frame(Name = c("Tom", "H", "Terry", "Barry"))
NameChangeR <- list('Tom'='Thomas T', 'H' = 'Harry P', 'Terry' = 'Terry T', 'Barry' = 'Barry W')


Data$Name <- chartr(paste(names(NameChangeR), collapse=''),
                    paste(NameChangeR, collapse=''),
                    Data$Name )
```

Comment: You probably want to do something with `?match` instead, matching your `Data$Name` to `names(NameChangeR)`

Comment: Can you enumerate each name and possible misspelling?

Comment: @thelatemail With named lists, there is no need for match. You can directly index into them NameChangeR[[data$Name]].

Comment: @AlexR - true, good point.

Comment: Look into soundex for matching names

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This sounds like it should be simple, but looping (or `*apply`ing) through options seems like an inefficient (from a reading perspective) way to go about it.

Starting with your 'misspelt' data:

```
Data <- data.frame(Name = c("Tom", "H", "Terry", "Barry"))
```

And randomising it a bit so that the answer doesn't depend on searching set 1 for name 1

```
DataMixed <- Data[sample(4), , drop=FALSE]
```

I turned the problem around into defining a list of possible misspellings of each correct name

```
BadSpellings <- list('Thomas T' = c('Tom', 'Thom', 'Tommy'),
                     'Harry P'  = c('Herry', 'H', 'Wizard'),
                     'Terry T'  = c('Terry', 'Trry'),
                     'Barry W'  = c('Other Barry', 'Barry'))
BadSpellings
#> $`Thomas T`
#> [1] "Tom"   "Thom"  "Tommy"
#> 
#> $`Harry P`
#> [1] "Herry"  "H"      "Wizard"
#> 
#> $`Terry T`
#> [1] "Terry" "Trry" 
#> 
#> $`Barry W`
#> [1] "Other Barry" "Barry"
```

I know it's not the most 'base' way to do it, but there's some great packages in the 'tidyverse' that help here: `tibble` allows list columns, and `tidyr` can unpack them.

```
library(tibble)
library(tidyr)

tbl <- tibble(Good = names(BadSpellings), Bad = BadSpellings)
tbl
#> # A tibble: 4 x 2
#>         Good       Bad
#>        <chr>    <list>
#>   1 Thomas T <chr [3]>
#>   2  Harry P <chr [3]>
#>   3  Terry T <chr [2]>
#>   4  Barry W <chr [2]>

merge(DataMixed, unnest(tbl, Bad), by.x = "Name", by.y = "Bad")
#> Name     Good
#> 1 Barry  Barry W
#> 2     H  Harry P
#> 3 Terry  Terry T
#> 4   Tom Thomas T
```

In the last step I've created a `tibble` of every combination of 'good' name and 'bad name', then I merged the 'bad' names with the 'misspelled' names.

Comment: Thanks @JonathanCarroll